# How do include a lot of JS in Magento 2 from a flat design

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I am working on adapting a third party JS heavy flat design into Magento 2. I have mostly what I need HTML wise moved around via XML instructions for my home page. Now that everything is in order there, I am trying to get all of the JS to run in the page but keep getting conflicts and errors one way or the other. Admittedly I have fairly new to Magento and requireJS

I would like to know how  get the following list of scripts to run in the page without breaking. The following works in a flat file, though it is a slow, so I may be misunderstanding something here.

```
    (function(require) {
(function () {

    var config = {
        "waitSeconds": 0,
        "shim": {
            "jquery/jquery-ui" : ["jquery"],
            "jquery/jquery-migrate": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery-ui"],
            "jquery/jquery.json": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery-migrate"],
            "jquery/jquery.base64": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery.json"],
            "jquery/jquery.md5": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery.base64"],
            "jquery/jquery.sha1": ["jquery", "jquery/jquery.md5"],
            "jquery/jquery.url": ["jquery/jquery.sha1"],
            "jquery/jquery.popup": ["jquery/jquery.url"],
            "jquery/jquery.validate": ["jquery/jquery.popup"],
            "jquery/jquery.mousewheel": ["jquery/jquery.validate"],
            "jquery/jquery.address": ["jquery/jquery.mousewheel"],
            "jquery/jquery.nicescroll": ["jquery/jquery.address"],
            "jquery/jquery.touchSwipe": ["jquery/jquery.nicescroll"],
            "jquery/jquery.backstretch": ["jquery/jquery.touchSwipe"],
            "tweenMax/TweenMax.min": ["jquery/jquery.backstretch"],
            "tweenMax/TimelineMax.min": ["tweenMax/TweenMax.min"],
            "cuppa": ["tweenMax/TimelineMax.min"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.dataHelp": ["cuppa"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.formHelp": ["cuppa/cuppa.dataHelp"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.mathHelp": ["cuppa/cuppa.formHelp"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.shop": ["cuppa/cuppa.mathHelp"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.mediaManager": ["cuppa/cuppa.shop"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.stringHelp": ["cuppa/cuppa.mediaManager"],
            "cuppa/cuppa.resources": ["cuppa/cuppa.stringHelp"],
            "jquery/jquery.lettering": ["cuppa/cuppa.resources"],
            "jquery/jquery.superscrollorama": ["jquery/jquery.lettering"],
            "animation": ["jquery/jquery.superscrollorama"],
            "animate_common": ["animation"],
            "functions2": ["animate_common"],
            "jquery.interactive_bg": ["functions2"],
        },
        "paths": {
            "jquery": "js/jquery/jquery",
            "jquery/jquery-ui": "js/jquery/jquery-ui",
            "jquery/jquery-migrate": "js/jquery/jquery-migrate",
            "jquery/jquery.json": "js/jquery/jquery.json",
            "jquery/jquery.base64": "js/jquery/jquery.base64",
            "jquery/jquery.md5": "js/jquery/jquery.md5",
            "jquery/jquery.sha1": "js/jquery/jquery.sha1",
            "jquery/jquery.url": "js/jquery/jquery.url",
            "jquery/jquery.popup": "js/jquery/jquery.popup",
            "jquery/jquery.validate": "js/jquery/jquery.validate",
            "jquery/jquery.mousewheel": "js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel",
            "jquery/jquery.address": "js/jquery/jquery.address",
            "jquery/jquery.nicescroll": "js/jquery/jquery.nicescroll",
            "jquery/jquery.touchSwipe": "js/jquery/jquery.touchSwipe",
            "jquery/jquery.backstretch": "js/jquery/jquery.backstretch",
            "tweenMax/TweenMax.min": "js/tweenMax/TweenMax.min",
            "tweenMax/TimelineMax.min": "js/tweenMax/TimelineMax.min",
            "tweenMax/TweenLite.min": "js/tweenMax/TweenLite.min",
            "cuppa": "js/cuppa/cuppa",
            "cuppa/cuppa.dataHelp": "js/cuppa/cuppa.dataHelp",
            "cuppa/cuppa.formHelp": "js/cuppa/cuppa.formHelp",
            "cuppa/cuppa.mathHelp": "js/cuppa/cuppa.mathHelp",
            "cuppa/cuppa.shop": "js/cuppa/cuppa.shop",
            "cuppa/cuppa.mediaManager": "js/cuppa/cuppa.mediaManager",
            "cuppa/cuppa.stringHelp": "js/cuppa/cuppa.stringHelp",
            "cuppa/cuppa.resources": "js/cuppa/cuppa.resources",
            "jquery/jquery.lettering": "js/jquery/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min",
            "jquery/jquery.superscrollorama": "js/jquery/jquery.superscrollorama",
            "animation": "js/animation",
            "animate_common": "js/animate_common",
            "functions2": "js/functions2",
            "jquery.interactive_bg": "js/jquery.interactive_bg",
        },

    };

    require.config(config);
    require([
        "jquery.interactive_bg",
    ]);
})();

})(require);
```

I shimmed the scripts in the order they loaded from the original template. jquery.interactive_bg seems to run the page animation.

Do I need to break this up into a map, or a separate JS config that intiializes it all and then put some code in the phtml?

Added side note: these scripts were just included consecutively, basically in this order to run in the original flat file.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!